# Instagram tagging

Tags: privacy, instagram, instagram-tags

My Instagram is currently private but I wanted to participate in a drawing if you tag/hashtag your photo and tag the @ persons name. My question is if my account is private will they see this hash tag and tag?

Answer (score 1):

No, they can't see your photo *unless* the person is following you, regardless of your caption having a person tag or hashtag. If your IG is private, only you and your followers can see your feed.